# make visible and invisible a div tag in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My question is very very simple.(I am a beginner in the css/html/javascript)

I would like to hide a div in mobile browser and show that div in the other devices (PC&Laptop).

how can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the responsive utilities documentation of Bootstrap at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities.

In this specific case you could for example use the class `visible-xs-block` to make a `<div>` only visible on the *xs* breakpoint that's used for mobile phones, and the class `hidden-xs` to make a `<div>` visible on all other breakpoints.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="visible-xs-block">only visible on xs</div>
<div class="hidden-xs">visible on everything but xs</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries. For example you could use:

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .my-div {
        display: none;
    }
}
</style>
```

More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I wouldn't use just `max-width` but rather `device-max-width`. That ensures that the element still appears on desktop/laptop, but would be hidden on a mobile/tablet device.